# html content added via jquery not getting methods (click,resizable) applied

Tags: jquery, html

I am loading (appending) some html content to a page via jQuery, like below.

```
var html = "<li id='"+id+"' class='sortable-item col3 left'>"+content+"</li>";
var parent = "some element name";                   
$('#'+parent).append(html);
```

When I try to attach an event (click) to above li element, it is not working.
say li id is "event".

```
$('#event').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Above code is not working. Can someone give me a solution or a workaround for this problem?

Comment: and is this give you an error or just the click is not triggered  ?

Comment: it is not giving an error. click event just not get triggered.

Comment: Thanks Dhiraj Bodicherla for the useful link. I got what I was looking for.